# Javascript post to php file then insert 2 times

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, post, route-provider

I'm trying to use simple SQL query in my web application but the query executed 2 times. I only want it to execute only one times, I can't find any wrong code in my web application. Please help !

[image: In the Network tab]

Here are my codes:

viewLogin.html

```
<form name="form1" method="post" >

<div class="container"  style="background-color:lightgreen;" align="center">
  <h1>Login</h1></br>
  <input type="text"  class="form-control" ng-model="logindata.Username" id="InputLastName" placeholder="Username" name="txtUsername"></br>
  <input type="password"  class="form-control" ng-model="logindata.Password" id="InputLastName" placeholder="Password" name="txtPassword"></br>
          <input ng-model="insertuser" ng-show="logindata.Username && logindata.Password" ng-click="login();" type="submit" value="Login"class="btn btn-primary">


</div></form>
```

viewLogin.js

```
angular.module('myApp.viewLogin', ['ngRoute'])

    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/viewLogin', {
            templateUrl: 'viewLogin/viewLogin.html',
            controller: 'Logincontroller'
        });
    }])

    .controller('Logincontroller', function ($scope, $http) {


        $scope.login = function () {
            var path = "http://localhost/login.php";
            var headers = {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS",
                "Content-Type": "undefined",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With"
            }
            $scope.table = "users";
            $scope.ajouter = 1;
            $scope.logindata;
            var postdata = {

                'Username': $scope.logindata.Username,
                'Password': $scope.logindata.Password,
                'ajouter': $scope.ajouter,
                'table': $scope.table,
                'app': true
            };
            $http.post(path, postdata, headers
            ).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                if (data) {
                    if (data == "false") {
                        alert("no");
                    } else {
                        alert("ok");
                    }

                }

            });

        }
    });
```

login.php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods : GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, X-YOUR-CUSTOM-HEADER');
    header("Content-Type : application/json");
        header("Accept : application/json");

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
@$username = $request->Username;
@$password = $request->Password;
$charmap="1234ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUYWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$codRandom = str_shuffle($charmap);

$serverName = "localhost";
    $userName = "root";
    $userPassword = "";
    $dbName = "middlework";

    $conn = new mysqli($serverName,$userName,$userPassword,$dbName);
    mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");

echo $username;
echo $password;
/*$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."' and Password = '".$password."'";

    $objQuery = mysqli_query($conn,$strSQL) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $objResult = mysqli_fetch_array($objQuery) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    if(!$objResult){
        echo "false";
    }else{
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["token"] = $codRandom;
        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
        echo 'true, '.$_SESSION["token"] ;
        echo 'true, '.$_SESSION["username"] ;

    }*/
$conn->close();
?>
```

app.js

```
// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.view2',
  'myApp.viewLogin',
  'myApp.SaveCafeDetail',
  'myApp.version'
]).
config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

index.html

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" > 
<head>
  <link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="icon128-2x.png">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">-->
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/main.css">-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    input { 
    text-align: center;    
}
  </style>
</head>
  <body style="background-color:lightgreen;">


  <!--div class="jumbotron" style="background-color:lightblue;">
  <h1>Bootstrap Tutorial</h1>
  <p>Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.</p>
</div-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Thaishop Online</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#!/view1">หน้าหลัก <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#!/view2">วิธีการใช้งาน</a></li>
       <!-- <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>-->
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#!/view2">สมัครสมาชิก</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#!/viewLogin">เข้าสู่ระบบ</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<!--<img src="img\banner.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre"style="width: 100%; height: 350px;" >-->








  <div ng-view></div>
<!--<div ng-controller="FrmController">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="confirmed" ng-change="change()" id="ng-change-example1" />
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="confirmed" id="ng-change-example2" />
  <label for="ng-change-example2">Confirmed</label><br />
  <tt>debug = {{confirmed}}</tt><br/>
  <tt ng-init="change()">counter = {{counter}}</tt><br/>
</div>-->



  <script src="js/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>

  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="view1/view1.js"></script>
  <script src="view2/view2.js"></script>
  <script src="viewLogin/viewLogin.js"></script>
  <script src="viewSaveCafeDetail/viewSaveCafeDetail.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Comment: I dont see any issue in your HTML and Js code except for inappropriate </br> tags

Comment: Do you know if the html form / javascript is being executed twice or is it only your php function that is being executed twice? Knowing the answer to that will tell you a lot about the issue you're having.

Comment: Thanks for replies guys, Yes @Angular_10 I can't find any wrong code but it still have problem.

Comment: @Jacksonkr I accept that I don't know which one is cause the problem, but first execute has no value from text box, it just post ""(null) value to php and then second it has a value from text box which is fine. I just want it to execute only one time.

Comment: @KitsakornP Are you familiar with webdeveloper tools? If you use chrome it's ctrl(or cmd)+alt+i - go to the "network" tab and when you submit the form you'll the transmission to `login.php`. If you see it twice then your issue is front end. If it only happens once then you know your issue is backend. Either way you've quickly solved 50% of the problem.

Comment: The code use ngRoute. Do the other modules include configs of $routeProvider? If so, please include them the question.

Comment: @Jacksonkr Yes sir it has two.

Answer (score 0):

So you didnt include angular 2 times :)

But can you add this in `viewLogin.html`, i think its did 2 time because you submit it aswell (input submit) :

```
ng-click=""login(); $event.stopPropagation();"
```

Comment: Why is this an answer?

Comment: I added please take a look. Thanks for helping !

Comment: @MaxiemeK Thank for answering ! I added your code but nothing change, another clue is first transmission has angular.js as an initiator and second has other as an initiator, why ?

Comment: @KitsakornP Can you put a screen of resources loaded : Inspector > Network, its look like you have 2 angular.js :)

Comment: @MaximeK I added a picture on lowest of my post, thank you so much for helping.